# Como fazer upload de um arquivo para CloudFlare?

Tags: c#, httpclient

Eu quero subir um arquivo para cloudflare, mas antes disso, ela usa protocolo [tus](https://tus.io/).

Segue o código a seguir:

```
var cloudflare = new HttpClient();
var zoneId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var email = "seuemail@hotmail.com";
var key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var url = $"https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/{zoneId}/media";

var fileinfo = new FileInfo(@"caminho do arquivo");

using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), url))
{
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Auth-Email", email);
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Auth-Key", key);
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Tus-Resumable", "1.0.0");
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Upload-Length", fileinfo.Length.ToString());
    request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(fileinfo.FullName));
    var response = await cloudflare.SendAsync(request);
}
```

A pós de executar `SendAsync()`, retorna código 201. Até agora está tudo bem.

Mas na hora de listar [todos os vídeos](https://api.cloudflare.com/#stream-videos-list-videos), me parece que não salvou. Segue o código de retorno ao listar vídeos:

```
{
    "result": [],
    "success": true,
    "errors": [],
    "messages": []
}
```

Porque não está salvando arquivo ? O que estou fazendo de errado ?

Segue a documentação [CloudFlare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/stream/recipes/batch-upload/).

Segue api curl [CloudFlare](https://api.cloudflare.com/#stream-videos-initiate-a-video-upload).